# How to get battery usage from cpu usage in android

Tags: android, cpu-usage, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any equation to find battery usage based on cpu usage by the process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003895/is-there-any-equation-to-find-battery-usage-based-on-cpu-usage-by-the-process)

I got cpu usage from following link [Get Memory Usage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/how-to-get-memory-usage-and-cpu-usage-in-android). Can any one give idea about how much battery(in joules or watt) consumed to use this amount of cpu. Is there any formula to calculate it. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Can any one give idea about how much battery(in joules or watt) consumed to use this amount of cpu

At best, that will vary by the actual CPU. Depending on the CPU, it might also vary by the mode the CPU (or perhaps core) is in (e.g., Intel SpeedStep-style technology).

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. If I get hard coded value of all cpu constants how can I relate them with battery usage. Can you please explain with a equation.